# Indesign - how to change the style of the page numbers?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am using [this template](https://www.bestindesigntemplates.com/brochure/indesign-elegant-corporate-brochure/).
I can change everything, however I can't find the right option to change the color of the page numbers. The default is blue.

I tried to read the official [adobe guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/layout-design-9.html), but I can't find the answe to my question there. And I am still learning to use Id. Probably there are some functions I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

How can I change the color of those little squares?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on the masterpage B (In the pages panel. Window -> pages). There you can simply select the square and change the color.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could be that they are in the Master Pages?
On your right hand-side, there is your "Pages" menu. On top you can find the Master Pages.
Double click on Master A, and you'll be able to edit the number pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are two full-spread page masters in this template, and the ***B***-*Master* is the one applied to all the internal pages, containing the page numbering square - once you have *that* page master onscreen, you can change the colour of the underlying square quite easily.

hope that helps.